# AutoSizeTextType not working in layout

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am using from `autoSizeTextType` but does not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/title_total_amount_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="AAAAAAAasdaDawdasdqwdAD ASDKNALKDNAJFND FJSLDFJMASdsfsfwerfdsfwerewrefsdfF EFSDF KsndfkJABSF.JDBSNFJSDBZX KDN.FAKFBBBBBBXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
```

Comment: what is not working ? where is the log if it's the error ? :)

Comment: Show your result screen, why it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 1):

please make sure proper dependancy like appcompat, support

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Here, I have done a simple example, please check out this, that might help in finding issues.

Sample:   **[AutoSizingTextViewinKotlin](https://github.com/dharmakshetri/AutoSizingTextViewinKotlin)**

Output Looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade your buildToolsVersion **26.0.0 or greater** and compileSdkVersion to **26 or greater**.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html#setting-textview-autosize

> If you set autosizing in an XML file, it is not recommended to use the
>   value "wrap_content" for the layout_width or layout_height attributes
>   of a TextView. It may produce unexpected results.

you can try like this :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just upgrade your support lib to beta2.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta2'
```

And change your project build.gradle to:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Output like this..

[image]