# Android autoSize cuts off text in TextView bottom line

Tags: android

I have such textview in my layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/text_body"
                style="@style/TvFontSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_color"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_header" />
```

with such style:

```
<style name="TvFontSize">
    <item name="android:autoSizeMaxTextSize">100sp</item>
    <item name="android:autoSizeMinTextSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:autoSizeStepGranularity">2sp</item>
    <item name="android:autoSizeTextType">uniform</item>
</style>
```

and long text is cut off as can see:

[image]

full layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/bottom_nav_color"
            tools:context=".pollsModule.IntroFinalFragment">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.SubtitleText"
                    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/polls_title"
                        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@color/polls_color"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbarContainer" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/text_header"
                style="@style/TvFontSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_color"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/text_body"
                style="@style/TvFontSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="dfjjnfdjnfdjndfjnfdjfjdnjnfdjndfdfjfdjnfnjddfjjnfdjnfdjndfjnfdjfjdnjnfdjndfdfjfdjnfnjddfjjnfdjnfdjndfjnfdjfjdnjnfdjndfdfjfdjnfnjddfjjnfdjnfdjndfjnfdjfjdnjnfdjndfdfjfdjnfnjddfjjnfdjnfdjndfjnfdjfjdnjnfdjndfdfjfdjnfnjddfjjnfdjnfdjndfjnfdjfjdnjnfdjndfdfjfdjnfnjddfjjnfdjnfdjndfjnfdjfjdnjnfdjndfdfjfdjnfnjddfjjnfdjnfdjndfjnfdjfjdnjnfdjndfdfjfdjnfnjddfjjnfdjnfdjndfjnfdjfjdnjnfdjndfdfjfdjnfnjddfjjnfdjnfdjndfjnfdjfjdnjnfdjndfdfjfdjnfnjd"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_color"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_header" />


            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/next_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
                app:autoSizeMinTextSize="6sp"
                app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_body" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

I can't imagine how to fix it. I tried to use:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:singleLine="false"
```

but it didn't help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This attribute affects your `TextView`. Just remove this attribute from your `style` part.

```
<item name="android:autoSizeTextType">uniform</item>
```

For enabling `autoSizeTextType`. You have to make your `textView` height Hardcore means in fixed size like `android:layout_height="300dp"` or `match parent`.

I hope it helps.

Thank you @Andrew for your clarification.

Comment: this line as I understood is used for enabling responsive features, on the other hand we will default none value what is written in docs

Comment: @Andrew `responsive features`? Your default textView shows responsiveness on all devices. If not please show me where the default text size does not show responsive. my recommendation is to remove this and add font size to your textView.

Comment: I thought that it adds responsivness to textview that is why decided to use it)

Comment: @Andrew for enabling `autoSizeTextType` you have to make your textView height `Hardcore` means in fixed size like `android:layout_height="300dp"` or `match parent`. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48165921/16765223

Comment: hm... okay, I got it, I thought that only added these fields we can see responsive size

Comment: @Andrew so, can I change my answer with this text?

Comment: yes sure it will be great

Answer (score 1):

your `TextView` should probably have height set to `wrap_content` instead of `0dp`...

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: thank you for your response but it didn't help me with this problem :( I tried it some time before posting this question

Comment: I saw that when I remove style field in the view my text manages to fill textview, it is good but what about responsive font size